# Influence of carbon dioxide concentration on the rate of photosynthesis

Tags: photosynthesis

The experiment to prove that carbon dioxide concentration influences the rate of photosynthesis:
[Click here to see the image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5hIsG-vnNz9NzVmbEMxUGVqanc)

The experiment is repeated after adding some sodium hydrogencarbonate (which dissolves in water to produce carbon dioxide) to the water. It is observed that more oxygen bubbles are produced, and thus this shows the increased photosynthesis rate.

**My question:** The equation for the dissolution of sodium hydrogencarbonate is NaHCO₃ *(s)* ⟶ NaOH *(aq)* + CO₂ *(aq)*. But won't the sodium hydroxide turn the solution *basic* and ***also*** influence the rate of photosynthesis?

Thanks in advance,
Ramana

Comment: @ bpedit. One of my friends (who is a biologist) said that when hydrogencarbonate dissolves, it forms carbonic acid which turns the solution **acidic**. But how? He says that the hydrogencarbonate combines with the hydrogen ions in solution to form carbonic acid......

Comment: Unimaginable that this question passes unanswered for over three years. It is very important to understand the advantages of increased carbon dioxide levels.